# ng-disabled myForm.$invalid not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've tried different methods on how to make my form submit button be disabled if the user hasn't filled all the required fields

I'm trying to understand how this works since it happens randomly and I always use a similar approach.

Here's the html:

```
<form name="newContactForm" novalidate>
  <md-card layout="column" layout-align="center" layout-wrap>
   <md-card-content flex="50">
     <div layout="row" layout-align="center" layout-wrap>
       <md-input-container flex="25">
         <label>Name</label>
         <input name="name" ng-model="newContact.name" required>
       </md-input-container>
       <md-input-container flex="25">
         <label>Telephone</label>
         <input name="tel" ng-model="newContact.tel" required>
       </md-input-container>
       <md-input-container flex="25">
         <label>Email</label>
         <input name="email" ng-model="newContact.email" required>
       </md-input-container>
       <md-input-container flex="25">
         <label>Title</label>
         <input name="title" ng-model="newContact.title" required>
       </md-input-container>
       <md-input-container flex="100">
         <label>Notes</label>
         <textarea name="notes" ng-model="newContact.notes" required md-maxlength="150" maxlength="150"></textarea>
       </md-input-container>
     </div>
   </md-card-content>
   <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
     <md-button ng-disabled="newContactForm.$invalid" ng-click="create(newContact)">Submit</md-button>
     <md-button>Cancel</md-button>
   </md-card-actions>
  </md-card>
</form>
```

This still doesn't disabled the `Submit` button, what am I doing wrong here?

**MORE INFO**

I have the form in an `md-dialog` if that helps.

I also tried doing a

```
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log($scope.newContactForm.$valid);
}, 2000);
```

which returns `Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined`.

Comment: can you please try `button` instead of `md-button`. or please make sure all fields of form should have name attribute.

Comment: Put this `{{newContactForm}}` to your html, then you can follow the changes in form object and you will be able to find the reason. Your code should be ok.

Comment: http://codepen.io/next1/pen/YWKRPN it is working fine. please provide a specific case when it's not wokring.

Comment: hi @nextt1 I've edited the question. I've tried `console.log($scope.newContactForm.$valid);` but returns as undefined

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach that doesn't print anything? o.o

Comment: What is your angular version?

Comment: Check that pen again. It is working fine with dialoge box too.

Answer (score 0):

Try saying `!valid` instead of `invalid`, as in

`<md-button ng-disabled="!newContactForm.$valid" ng-click="create(newContact)">Submit</md-button>`

Please let me know if that works

Comment: doing this now just makes it disabled even after filling the fields

Comment: @Johhan: Note `$valid` instead of `$invalid`

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach I tried it, no luck, also when I try to add `ng-messages` for `newContactForm.name.$error` it doesn't work either, it's like it's not reading the fields or something.